# How to make Nvidia Optimus work on Kubuntu 15.10?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, optimus

I thought the Nvidia driver would install itself properly since it offered me Nvidia drivers installation after fresh system installation. It did not go well.

So, how to make Nvidia Optimus work on Kubuntu 15.10 properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a step-by-step guide for what I did to make Nvidia Optimus work on Kubuntu 15.10 64-bit. Note that I describe the user friendly way because it's meant for all users to be able to do it.

1. In the Device Manager choose the recommended driver, in my case **nvidia-352**
2. If you don't have it already, in Muon Discover find Muon Package Manager and install it
3. Start Muon Package Manager, type nvidia
4. Make sure all of the following packages are installed, as you will probably have to install some of them

   [image: Nvidia Packages]
5. From the menu start Konsole and type `sudo kate /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf`
6. Change the following lines

---

```
Driver=
```

to

```
Driver=nvidia
```

and

```
KernelDriver=nvidia-current
```

to

```
KernelDriver=nvidia-352
```

and

```
LibraryPath=
```

Sorry I don't remember what was there.

to

```
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-352:/usr/lib32/nvidia-352
```

and

```
XorgModulePath=
```

Sorry I don't remember what was there.

to

```
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-352/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
```

---

7. Reboot
8. From menu start Konsole and type `optirun steam` if you play games via Steam.